# How to Create a Method that only accepts elements that implement Iterable

Tags: java, collections, types, generics, iterable

I want to write a function printAll(), which accepts only those elements that implement that implement Iterable so that I can iterate over them and print the elements. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`public static void printAll(final Iterable<?> toIterate)`.